# SQL Oracle error: ORA-00904

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a table and I typed this command:

```
SQL> create table accident(report_number integer primary key,
  2  date varchar(20),
  3  location varchar(20));
```

I got this error:

```
date varchar(20),
*
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

Can anyone tell me where the error is and how to rectify it?

Comment: Having a column named "date" of type `VARCHAR` smells like bad deisgn - shouldn't it rather be of type `DATE`?

Comment: Please consider using `varchar2` instead of `varchar` which is [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/server.901/a90120/ch4_dep.htm#10006)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATE is a reserved word and can't be used as a column name.

Answer (score 0):

`Date` is a reserved word, to use it for column names, surround it with quotas **"column-name"**

**ex:**

```
create table abcd(
"date" date
);

insert into abcd values (sysdate);

select "date" from abcd;
```

But note that when using quoats, the column names will be case sensitive

**ex:**

`select "Date" from abcd` will result in an **"Date": invalid identifier**